# Sort a list using comparison from another list

Tags: java

I have two list, one character ,the other list freq. I want to sort character according to freq.

I did: // I used c here instead of character

```
Collections.sort(c,new Comparator()
                {
                    public int compare(Character c1, Character c2)
                    {
                        return (Comparable)freq.get(c.indexOf(c1)).compareTo( freq.get(c.indexOf(c2)));
                    }
                });
```

But the code gives an error.

```
chef_code.java:33: error: <anonymous chef_code$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method compare(Object,Object) in Comparator
                {
                ^
chef_code.java:36: error: local variable c is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                        return (Comparable)freq.get(c.indexOf(c1)).compareTo( freq.get(c.indexOf(c2)));
                                                                                       ^
chef_code.java:36: error: local variable freq is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                        return (Comparable)freq.get(c.indexOf(c1)).compareTo( freq.get(c.indexOf(c2)));
                                                                              ^
chef_code.java:36: error: local variable c is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                        return (Comparable)freq.get(c.indexOf(c1)).compareTo( freq.get(c.indexOf(c2)));
                                                    ^
chef_code.java:36: error: local variable freq is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                        return (Comparable)freq.get(c.indexOf(c1)).compareTo( freq.get(c.indexOf(c2)));
                                           ^
chef_code.java:36: error: incompatible types
                        return (Comparable)freq.get(c.indexOf(c1)).compareTo( freq.get(c.indexOf(c2)));
                               ^
  required: int
  found:    Comparable
```

Please help.

Comment: What is `,the other freq`? what `does not work.` ?

Comment: "gives an error"..what error?

Comment: You should provide more code. This fragment alone cannot give us a sufficient outlook of the case/problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making c and freq as final and don't cast to Comparable before return

Original

```
return (Comparable)freq.get(c.indexOf(c1)).compareTo( freq.get(c.indexOf(c2)));
```

New

```
return freq.get(c.indexOf(c1)).compareTo( freq.get(c.indexOf(c2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write: `new Comparator<Character>`  (Assuming you deal with a collection of `characters`)

instead of `new Comparator`.

Indeed, look at the `Comparator` interface's signature:

```
public interface Comparator<T> {
  int compare(T o1, T o2);
}
```

If you don't precise a type, it assumes `Object`, and this is strictly not what you want.

I try this code, and it compiles (under JDK 7):

```
private static List<Character> freq = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collections.sort(c, new Comparator<Character>() {
            public int compare(Character c1, Character c2) {
                return freq.get(c.indexOf(c1)).compareTo(freq.get(c.indexOf(c2)));
            }
        });

    }
```

As you didn't provide the whole code, please explain in what it would be different than yours.

Comment: @user3062693 If your code is similar to the one I presented, I confirm it does well work.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
    Collections.sort(c, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String c1, String c2) {
            return freq.get(c.indexOf(c1)).compareTo(
                    freq.get(c.indexOf(c2)));
        }
    });
```

considering, both `c` and `freq` are Lists in your program:

```
    final ArrayList<String> c = new ArrayList<>();
    //add elements to c

    final ArrayList<String> freq = new ArrayList<>();
    //add elements to freq
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to use Object as argument

   ```
           public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               return 0;
           }
   ```
2. You should cast it accordingly

   ```
          public int compare(Object c1, Object c2)
           {
               YourClass obj1 =(YourClass)c1;
               YourClass obj2 =(YourClass)c2;
               return freq.get(c.indexOf(obj1)).compareTo( freq.get(c.indexOf(obj2)));
           }
   ```
3. Why you return Comparable, you should return int
4. Declare final variable to access freq if required